# how to store new record to other table without duplicate using trigger

Tags: sql, database, triggers, mariadb

I want to copy data records from table dvc0004 to table dvc0005 without duplicating data using triggers. 
here's my trigger:

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = ''@''
TRIGGER testing_MesinAbsen.trigger1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON testing_MesinAbsen.dvc0004
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dvc0005 d WHERE d.NIK = NEW.NIK AND d.Enroll=NEW.Enroll)) THEN
    INSERT INTO dvc0005 (NIK,Enroll) 
    VALUES (NEW.NIK,NEW.Enroll); 
    END IF;
END
```

I try to insert a new record, so the following notice appears: 
[image]

Here's my table: 
*on dvc0004*

| NIK | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 00:01:00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 00:03:00 |
| 4 | 2021-03-01 00:04:00 |

*on dvc0005*

| NIK | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 00:03:00 |
| 4 | 2021-03-01 00:04:00 |

this is the result I want: 
**on dvc0005 :**

| NIK | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 00:01:00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 00:03:00 |
| 4 | 2021-03-01 00:04:00 |

When viewed from the desired results table, the data record *NIK : 2* was successfully inserted in dvc0005 without duplicate data insertion

Comment: Can you show us your insert statement into the dvc0004 table. Also, does this sentence "2 was successfully inserted in dvc0005 without duplicate data insertion" means that the record was inserted as expected in dvc0005 or that is what you want to happen but is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this trigger can running execute on mariaDB

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = ''@''
TRIGGER testing_MesinAbsen.trigger1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON testing_MesinAbsen.dvc0004
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dvc0005 d WHERE d.NIK = NEW.NIK AND d.Enroll=NEW.Enroll)) THEN
    INSERT INTO dvc0005 (NIK,Enroll) 
    VALUES (NEW.NIK,NEW.Enroll); 
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine. Please check.

Create table `dvc0005` and insert rows:

```
 create table dvc0005 (NIK int, Enroll datetime);


 insert into dvc0005 values(1,  '2021-03-01 00:00:00');
 insert into dvc0005 values(3,  '2021-03-01 00:03:00');
 insert into dvc0005 values(4,  '2021-03-01 00:04:00');
```

Create table `dvc0004`

```
 create table dvc0004(NIK int, Enroll datetime);
```

Create trigger:

```
 CREATE 
 TRIGGER trigger1
     AFTER INSERT
     ON dvc0004
     FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dvc0005 d WHERE d.NIK = NEW.NIK AND d.Enroll=NEW.Enroll)) THEN
     INSERT INTO dvc0005 (NIK,Enroll) 
     VALUES (NEW.NIK,NEW.Enroll); 
     END IF;
 END
```

Insert into `dvc0004`

```
 insert into dvc0004 values(1,  '2021-03-01 00:00:00');
 insert into dvc0004 values(2,  '2021-03-01 00:01:00');
 insert into dvc0004 values(3,  '2021-03-01 00:03:00');
 insert into dvc0004 values(4,  '2021-03-01 00:04:00');




 select * from dvc0005;
```

Output:

| NIK | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 00:03:00 |
| 4 | 2021-03-01 00:04:00 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 00:01:00 |

```
 select * from dvc0005;
```

Output:

| NIK | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2021-03-01 00:03:00 |
| 4 | 2021-03-01 00:04:00 |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 00:01:00 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=edd2946abf4fc0087a1084a7fbd03365)*

Comment: This makes me confused that the fiddle trigger can run normally, but when I implement it in my database, it gets an error and gets a notice like that

Comment: Please check  column names of both table in your database. Which version of mariadb are you using?